# Is it possible to use grub2 with a linux root partition under Soft-RAID5?

Tags: linux, raid, grub, raid-5

I need some more space in my computer, therefore I want some basic changes be done. One of those is setting a RAID up for all files to be a bit more robust (I have just had a hd crash, so I am a bit paranoid at the moment).

The old setup:
One dedicated root and one boot partition on a HD. Nothing special. The other partitions are located under LVM (does not matter here).

The new (desired) setup:
The two partitions `/` and `/boot` are merged into one single partition and managed under a RAID5. The LVM will be under another RAID5.

What I did: I created on all new HDs the partitions: One for the root RAID, one for swap and one for the rest. I created the root file system and copied the relevant data there. I modified `/etc/fstab` to use the correct device (RAID partition and not mounting on `/boot`). Then I cheated in the `grub.cfg` of the *old* system such that I can boot into the new root. Just a quick hack to be able to boot up.

Now the problem arises: I rebooted and was able to start the *new* (RAID based) root file system. There I made a `update-grub` and installed grub on another HD. So now I am able to select via the bios which grub version to use. If I select the *old* one, the RAID based root file system can be loaded and everything works. If I try this from the *new* grub version (automatically generated and using data only from the RAID partition), I end up in a grub rescue console. I get some error like: `error: No such device ...`. Here the UUID of the RAID Device is inserted.

So my question(s):

- Can grub generaly load its data from a raid device?
- Are there any special actions needed?
- Is it possible with and level and metadata version?
- Do I need a separate `/boot` partition to allow correct booting?

Thanks

PS: It is a debian squeeze system.

PPS: [Working grub configuration](http://pastebin.com/VPXvyh74) and [not working configuration](http://pastebin.com/aFmkkWCa) for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it running. I had to uncomment the line `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in `/etc/default/grub` and then do a `update-grub`. I also added `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="raid mdraid"` at the end (not sure if needed).